# Heap insertion and deletion with mininum time complexity

Tags: c, time-complexity, heap

Is it possible to insert a element to a heap or delete a element from a heap when we implement the heap with array with time complexity O(1)?

Comment: If you could then you could have sorting algorithm faster than o(n log n). Therefore one must have additional assumption on the value of keys. Like limiting their range

Answer (score 1):

Insertion? no. If you want it to be a heap you need to sort while inserting, so I guess you end up having log-n anyway.

Deletion? maybe. If you associate the heap with a map where the inserted value is the map key and the map value is the position of the inserted value into the heap, then you can find the position of the element in constant time, and delete it as well in constant time

Comment: Wikipedia's [Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) page show many [variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)#Comparison_of_theoretic_bounds_for_variants) with an O(1) insert time. And all variants have O(log N) deletion. So you're contradicting Wikipedia in both half of your answer.

Comment: @ikegami - The question was about a Heap implemented using an **array**. Arrays  have O(1) insertion only if the array has only one member. The Wikipedia page has other options for Heap implementations.

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you gave a better deletion time than even the array based approaches listed there.

Comment: Unfortunately I miss the OP asking for an array implementation; I can't figure out a deletion on an array with constant-time, my mistake

Comment: Also, if you're pushing on the top of the heap (and hopefully the memory is preallocated), array insertion could be O(1).

Answer (score 1):

No, this isn't possible - at least, assuming that the only way to determine the relative ordering of elements is by making comparisons.

Suppose you *could* do this. Then we could sort a list of n items in time O(n) as follows:

- Insert all n elements into the heap in time O(n).
- Repeatedly do the following:

  - Find the smallest element in the heap in time O(1).
  - Remove that element from the heap in time O(1).

Overall, this would give an O(n)-time comparison-based sorting algorithm, which is impossible because no such algorithm exists.